# Understanding Pickling in Python

Tags: python, pickle, python-2.7

I have recently got an assignment where I need to put a dictionary (where each key refers to a list) in pickled form. The only problem is I have no idea what pickled form is. Could anyone point me in the right direction of some good resources to help me learn this concept?

Comment: @Wooble: I know its totally off topic, but Google search varies with your location, search history, even email/chat history ;). But yes, +1 for pointing to the docs.

Comment: @0xc0de Right. For me the top entry *is* the preserved vegetable. :-) Guess I should start coding more.

Comment: See also: [How to use pickle to store / load data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33245595/562769)

Answer (score 107):

The pickle module implements a fundamental, but powerful algorithm for serializing and de-serializing a Python object structure.

**Pickling -** is the process whereby a Python object hierarchy is converted into a byte stream, and **Unpickling -** is the inverse operation, whereby a byte stream is converted back into an object hierarchy.

Pickling (and unpickling) is alternatively known as **serialization**, **marshalling**, or **flattening**.

```
import pickle

data1 = {'a': [1, 2.0, 3, 4+6j],
         'b': ('string', u'Unicode string'),
         'c': None}

selfref_list = [1, 2, 3]
selfref_list.append(selfref_list)

output = open('data.pkl', 'wb')

# Pickle dictionary using protocol 0.
pickle.dump(data1, output)

# Pickle the list using the highest protocol available.
pickle.dump(selfref_list, output, -1)

output.close()
```

To read from a pickled file -

```
import pprint, pickle

pkl_file = open('data.pkl', 'rb')

data1 = pickle.load(pkl_file)
pprint.pprint(data1)

data2 = pickle.load(pkl_file)
pprint.pprint(data2)

pkl_file.close()
```

source - https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html

Comment: This is simply one of the best code samples I have ever seen. Beautifully formatted and wonderfully succinct. Thank you.

Comment: I didn't get why `data1 = pickle.load(pkl_file)` didn't load complete file (data.pkl) ?

Comment: Does pickling require a file output parameter? How do you keep the serialized object to store it elsewhere?

Comment: For those using Python 3: `pickle.dump(data1, output)` defaults to `pickle.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL` (protocol 3 at time of writing this comment) rather than protocol 0.

Answer (score 26):

Pickling is a mini-language that can be used to convert the relevant state from a python object into a string, where this string uniquely represents the object.  Then (un)pickling can be used to convert the string to a live object, by "reconstructing" the object from the saved state founding the string.

```
>>> import pickle
>>> 
>>> class Foo(object):
...   y = 1
...   def __init__(self, x):
...     self.x = x
...     return
...   def bar(self, y):
...     return self.x + y
...   def baz(self, y):
...     Foo.y = y  
...     return self.bar(y)
... 
>>> f = Foo(2)
>>> f.baz(3)
5
>>> f.y
3
>>> pickle.dumps(f)
"ccopy_reg\n_reconstructor\np0\n(c__main__\nFoo\np1\nc__builtin__\nobject\np2\nNtp3\nRp4\n(dp5\nS'x'\np6\nI2\nsb."
```

What you can see here is that pickle doesn't save the source code for the class, but does store a reference to the class definition.  Basically, you can almost read the picked string… it says (roughly translated) "call copy_reg's reconstructor where the arguments are the class defined by `__main__.Foo` and then do other stuff".  The other stuff is the saved state of the instance.  If you look deeper, you can extract that "string x" is set to "the integer 2" (roughly: `S'x'\np6\nI2`).  This is actually a clipped part of the pickled string for a dictionary entry… the `dict` being `f.__dict__`, which is `{'x': 2}`.  If you look at the source code for `pickle`, it very clearly gives a translation for each type of object and operation from python to pickled byte code.

Note also that there are different variants of the pickling language.  The default is protocol 0, which is more human-readable.  There's also protocol 2, shown below (and 1,3, and 4, depending on the version of python you are using).

```
>>> pickle.dumps([1,2,3])
'(lp0\nI1\naI2\naI3\na.'
>>> 
>>> pickle.dumps([1,2,3], -1)
'\x80\x02]q\x00(K\x01K\x02K\x03e.'
```

Again, it's still a dialect of the pickling language, and you can see that the protocol 0 string says "get a list, include I1, I2, I3", while the protocol 2 is harder to read, but says the same thing.  The first bit `\x80\x02` indicates that it's protocol 2 -- then you have `]` which says it's a list, then again you can see the integers 1,2,3 in there.  Again, check the source code for pickle to see the exact mapping for the pickling language.

To reverse the pickling to a string, use load/loads.

```
>>> p = pickle.dumps([1,2,3])
>>> pickle.loads(p)
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: As a beginner, I was having this question in my head, what kind of stuff does pickle do on the inside ? This answer addressed that more than others.

Comment: Very nice answer! I have tried to save an object of class `A`, modify class attribute of `A`, and then load back the saved object. I observed that the change was reflected in the new object. So `pickle` allows for modifications in the class attributes but not on the instance attributes?

Comment: `pickle` serializes a class by reference, so if the class definition changes... a pickled instance that was saved using the old class definition will point to the updated class definition.  This can potentially make the stored instance unable to load, or it can work and will load using the new class definition.  If you use `dill`, which can store the class definition with the instance, you have options whether to use the updated class or the old (stored) version.

Answer (score 11):

Pickling is just serialization: putting data into a form that can be stored in a file and retrieved later. Here are the docs on the `pickle` module:

http://docs.python.org/release/2.7/library/pickle.html

Answer (score 3):

http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#example

```
import pickle

data1 = {'a': [1, 2.0, 3, 4+6j],
         'b': ('string', u'Unicode string'),
         'c': None}

selfref_list = [1, 2, 3]
selfref_list.append(selfref_list)

output = open('data.pkl', 'wb')

# Pickle dictionary using protocol 0.
pickle.dump(data1, output)

# Pickle the list using the highest protocol available.
pickle.dump(selfref_list, output, -1)

output.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

Pickling in Python is used to serialize and de-serialize Python objects, like dictionary in your case. I usually use `cPickle` module as it can be much faster than the `Pickle` module.

```
import cPickle as pickle    

def serializeObject(pythonObj):
    return pickle.dumps(pythonObj, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

def deSerializeObject(pickledObj):
    return pickle.loads(pickledObj)
```

Comment: What is the use of Highest.protocol  ?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes we want to save the objects to retrieve them later (Even after the Program that generated the data has terminated). Or we want to transmit the object to someone or something else outside our application. [`Pickle` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) is used for serializing and deserializing the object.

```
serializing object (Pickling): Create a representation of an object.
deserializing object (Unpickling): Re-load the object from representation.

dump: pickle to file
load: unpickle from file
dumps: returns a pickled representation. We can store it in a variable.
loads: unpickle from the supplied variable.
```

Example:

```py
import pickle

print("Using dumps and loads to store it in variable")
list1 = [2, 4]
dict1 = {1: list1, 2: 'hello', 3: list1}
pickle_dict = pickle.dumps(dict1)
print(pickle_dict)

dict2 = pickle.loads(pickle_dict)
print(dict2)

# obj1==obj2 => True
# obj1 is obj2 => False

print(id(dict1.get(1)), id(dict1.get(3)))
print(id(dict2.get(1)), id(dict2.get(3)))
print("*" * 100)
print("Using dump and load to store it in File ")

cars = ["Audi", "BMW", "Maruti 800", "Maruti Suzuki"]
file_name = "mycar.pkl"
fileobj = open(file_name, 'wb')
pickle.dump(cars, fileobj)
fileobj.close();

file_name = "mycar.pkl"
fileobj = open(file_name, 'rb')
mycar = pickle.load(fileobj)
print(mycar)
```

Answer (score -1):

**Pickling** allows you to **serialize and de-serializing** Python object structures. In short, Pickling is a way to convert a python object into a character stream so that this character stream contains all the information necessary to reconstruct the object in another python script.

```py
import pickle

def pickle_data():
    data = {
           'name': 'sanjay',
           'profession': 'Software Engineer',
           'country': 'India'
        }
    filename = 'PersonalInfo'
    outfile = open(filename, 'wb')
    pickle.dump(data,outfile)
    outfile.close()

pickle_data()
```