# Convert pickled value

Tags: python, django, pickle

One of the tables of my database in Django contains the dictionary below. When dumping the table as .csv and looking at the column where the dict is stored, I get some awkward results.

```
{""my_key"": 
{""__pickled__"":""gANjbnVtcHkuY29yZS5tdWx0aWFycmF5CnNjYWxhcgpxAGNudW1weQpkdHlwZQpxAVgCAAAAaThxAksASwGHcQNScQQoSwNYAQAAADxxBU5OTkr/////Sv////9LAHRxBmJDCAgAAAAAAAAAcQeGcQhScQku\n""}
}
```

In Python, the following yields an error asking for a specific encoding.

```
pickle.loads(bytes(gANjbnVtcHkuY29yZS5tdWx0aWFycmF5CnNjYWxhcgpxAGNudW1weQpkdHlwZQpxAVgCAAAAaThxAksASwGHcQNScQQoSwNYAQAAADxxBU5OTkr/////Sv////9LAHRxBmJDCAgAAAAAAAAAcQeGcQhScQku\n))
```

The result should be an integer value smaller than 10. How do I decode the pickled value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding Pickling in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501947/understanding-pickling-in-python)

Comment: Add the Traceback/Error to your Question.